# JavaFx StackedBarChart not ordered after categories

Tags: javafx, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have a problem with JavaFxs StackedBarChart: I can't manage to get the Data to be sorted in categorie order. The problem specifically is that i have to create Series for the Products (so that they are grouped together) but when i do that the chart is order in insertion order and not in the categories (in this case dates) order.

Thats the code i use to create the StackedBarChart:

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    final ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<Integer, List<XYChart.Data<String, Number>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> productNames = new HashMap<>();

    for(SoldProduct sp : products) {
        if (!map.containsKey(sp.getId())) {
            map.put(sp.getId(), new ArrayList<>());
            productNames.put(sp.getId(), sp.getName());
        }
        if(!dates.contains(sp.getDate().toString())){
            dates.add(sp.getDate().toString());
        }
        List<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> list = map.get(sp.getId());
        list.add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(sp.getDate().toString(), sp.getAmount()));
        map.put(sp.getId(), list);
    }

    ((CategoryAxis)barChart.getXAxis()).getCategories().setAll(dates);
    barChart.setCategoryGap((500.0/dates.size())/2);

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<XYChart.Data<String, Number>>> entry : map.entrySet()){
        final StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number> series = new StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>();
        series.setName(productNames.get(entry.getKey()));
        series.getData().addAll(entry.getValue());
        data.add(series);
    }

    barChart.setData(data);
```

I hope someone knows a solution for this problem and could provide me with a solution! Thanks a lot!

[image: How it looks now]

EDIT: by doing the following 'hack' before inserting the data i get the correct order

```
final StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number> notUsed = new StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>();
    notUsed.setName("Workaround JAVAFX BarChart Ordering Problem");
    for(String d : dates){
        notUsed.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(d, 0));
    }
    data.add(notUsed);
```

PS. i use the latest version: 1.8.0_77-b03 (since i read about an ordering problem in previous versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After trying out some different ideas i came up with a pretty simple solution, i just init the Barchart with the categories before doing any adding.

```
ObservableList<String> dates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for(SoldProduct sp : products) {  //Your data
        if(!dates.contains(sp.getDate().toString())){
            dates.add(sp.getDate().toString());
        }
    }
    ((CategoryAxis)barChart.getXAxis()).setCategories(dates);
```

Just do this before processing the data for the barChart.